# Take screenshots via keyboard app or iMessage app

Tags: ios, iphone, screenshot, uikeyboard, imessage

Is it possible to programmatically take screenshots from within a keyboard app or an iMessage app? If so, how?

Edit: to clarify, I would like to take screenshots of the entire screen (i.e. the currently open app) from within the keyboard/iMessage app.

Comment: Do you want screenshots of the keyboard / message app? Or are you trying to screenshot other apps (the Messages app or the app with the keyboard open)?

Comment: Screenshots of other apps while the keyboard is open.

Answer (score 5):

Since this action would be devastating for privacy of customers who use third-party keyboards or iMessage apps, it is not possible to collect screenshots of personal data in this manner, for obvious reasons.

The question specifically asks for a method to perform a potentially scammy action that is against [App Store Review Guidelines, Section 5.1.1 Data Collection and Storage](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#data-collection-and-storage):

> (iii) Developers that use their apps to surreptitiously discover
>   passwords or other private data will be removed from the Developer
>   Program.

This question has been flagged accordingly.

Comment: To clarify, I envisioned this happening only at the request of the user via e.g. tapping a button on a keyboard.

Comment: Users can already take screenshots via hardware button combinations if they need to.

Comment: Right, but it's cumbersome to repeatedly scroll and take a screenshot if the user wants to capture more than what can fit on the screen at a time. I'd like to implement functionality such that the user can press a single button, and screenshots or the entire scrollable area are automatically taken and stitched together.

Comment: This is different from what you originally asked. It might be possible. Post a new, rephrased question about it, and I’ll try answering.

Comment: Thank you @boletzar, I've posted a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43615790/take-screenshots-programmatically-of-entire-scrollable-area-in-ios

Answer (score -1):

**Use this code for taking a screenshot using UIToolBar**

```
extension UIViewController: UITextFieldDelegate{
    func addToolBar(textField: UITextField){
        var toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
        toolBar.translucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
        var screenshotButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Screenshot", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "donePressed")
        var cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "cancelPressed")
        var spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        textField.delegate = self
        textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }
    func screenshotButton(){
            func captureScreen() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
    }
    func cancelPressed(){
        view.endEditing(true) // or do something
    }
}
```

Though I still need to call the code below on all of my text fields.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addToolBar(addressField)
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify? What is a UIToolbar? Will this take a screenshot of the entire screen from within a keyboard or iMessage app?

Comment: use this for reference on toolbar https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitoolbar

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'm still unsure about whether this addresses my problem, however. Is the UIToolbar a component that can be added into an iMessage app or a keyboard app? If so, does the code you posted take a screenshot of the entire screen, or just of the iMessage/keyboard app?

Comment: This is for taking screenshots inside the app but the question is different.