# Take screenshots programmatically of entire scrollable area in iOS

Tags: ios, screenshot, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

Currently it is cumbersome for the user to repeatedly scroll and take a screenshot if they want to capture more than what can fit on the screen at a time.

I would like to implement functionality such that at the request of a user (e.g. via tapping a special button on a custom keyboard), screenshots of the entire scrollable area of the currently opened app are automatically taken and stitched together.

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Edit: to clarify, **the application containing the scrollable area is a third party application**, e.g. iMessage or Facebook.

Comment: [This Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display) shows how to 'screenshot' a UIView as a UIImage, this should lead to a solution ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the code at the post you linked to is intended to work from within the application containing the scrollable area. My question is specifically about taking screenshots of another application over which I have no control.